# How to arrange data in SQL?

Tags: oracle

I am using `Oracle SQL Plus`.

Please refer to screenshot for reference.

After deletion of data of column `sno=4`, I want the output of sno to be displayed in serial order ie *1,2,3,4* instead of *1,2,3,5.*

Please suggest the SQL query to achieve same.

[image: SQL]

Comment: @vhu  screenshot attached.

Comment: So you'd like to renumber the SNO column, without gaps?

Comment: @vhu yes..I would like to renumber the SNO column.

Comment: what's wrong with using text. people can actually cut and paste

Comment: @Jens I am using Oracle SQL* Plus.

Comment: @Anand Please correct the tag in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
select ROWNUM as SNO, NAME,DOJ from company order by SNO
```

Comment: @ImreL but in the question OP wrote he use Oracle SQL Plus. So i mentoned the tag is wrong.

Comment: changed tag, @Anand please mark this answer as solution if it solves your problem.

Comment: It might be useful to note the data is not actually modified in the database, but that you are not using it in your query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the numbering to be persistent, you will need to update the SNO for all the remaining records in the table.

What you have done, by deleting the row is say that "row number 4 no longer exists".  If you want to shuffle the remaining rows up, you will need to perform the following:

```
DELETE FROM company WHERE name='Flipkart';

UPDATE company SET sno=sno-1 WHERE sno>=4;
```

An alternative, if you don't want to alter the contents of the table itself.. But you want it to display correctly (specifically for this example)

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN sno <= 4 THEN sno 
       ELSE sno-1 
    END AS sno, 
    name,
    doj 
FROM company
ORDER BY sno;
```